# Find scripts that call a script in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

Is there a way in FileMaker, either by using the application features or by writing scripts, to find what scripts call a specific script?

This strikes me as an essential ability when debugging, and ironically my text editor does the same task as a matter of course when I hit ctrl-f.

The only way I have been able to find to do this is to print the entire set of scripts out to a PDF and then search that. Surely there is a better way.

Comment: Not in Filemaker itself, but yes in the DDR: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fdocumenting-schemas.html%23

Comment: And also in the *Copy as XML* file (though is tougher to find it there)..

Comment: NB I'm building a solution that runs an XSLT to transfrom XML DDRs to create a PDF containing a visual representation of the entire chain of dependencies of any object using GraphViz. Not that that's of any help to you, as it's not finished yet, but give it a couple of, er, years, and I may have something available people can use.

Answer (score 1):

The tool FMPerception can do that and more, but it is a paid tool and I find it rather expensive as most other FM helper tools. There is also 2empowerFM Plug-in Family: [www.2empowerFM.com](http://www.2empowerFM.com) that you can use to search and find in all your scripts, this is also a paid tool but not as expensive as others and this one can for sure help a lot in your daily developing of FileMaker.

Disclosure: I don't work for either one of those companies.